# Knockout Mapping an array but not its child properties?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm trying to use the knockout mapping plugin, I have it working fine except for one part.

I have an array of objects, I want the array to be observable, but I don't want the objects within the array to be observable at this time.

For example:

Main

- Tabs[]

Tab

- Title
- Id
- Windows[]

Window

- Title
- Id
- Location
- etc

  ```
  var MainMapping = {
    'Tabs': {
      create: function(options) {
          return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {'ignore': ['Id']}, model.tab);
      }
    }
  };
  ```

I would like it so that none of the Window properties are observable, yet I want the Windows array to be.

Can anyone give me some tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer I have come up with:

```
var Main = function() {
    return { ....}
}();

var mainMap = {
    'Tabs':{
        create:function(options){
            return new Tab(options.data);
        }
    }
};

function Tab(data){
    var defaults = { ...}
    data = $.extend(true, defaults, data);

    var tabMap = {
        'copy': ['id'],
        key: function(data) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id);
        },
        'windows': {
            create: function(options) {
                return new myWindow(options.data);
            }
        }
    };

    ko.mapping.fromJs(data, tabMap, this);
}

function myWindow(data){
    var defaults = { ....};
    return $.extend(true, defaults, data);
}

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mainMap, Main);
ko.applyBindings(Main, $('#Main')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) has the copy option, which creates JS properties with the value copied over (i.e. I don't think you can put 'Window.Title' as a property map for the top level view model, though feel free to try it!), which sounds like what you're after. However, as it's a child, I'm not sure that it will work, so you might want to look at the create mapping, where you can control mapping completely, and you could either straight copy your window data object into the Windows array, or else use the mapping plugin on that too, and use the copy mapping on it.